# Hide text on product page when id = x

Tags: template, product-view

On a (donuts) site I'd like to show some different text on a product page with ID 171.

The quantity I have translated to "ammount of boxes", but on one product page I need to change the text "ammount of boxes" to "quantity or ammount"

I'm not sure where to look, when I look at `view.phtml` (`/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`)

```
< ?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ? >
```

In what file do I change this? And how? Is there a way to say: when ID is: x , then do: y, else: z?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,edit the file in

**app\design\frontend\package\theme\template\catalog\product\view\addtocart.phtml**

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php if($_product->getId() == 171) //Change Product Id as per your reqiurement
{
    $label = $this->__('quantity or ammount');
}
else
{
    $label = $this->__('ammount of boxes');
}
?>
```

Change the below code:

From

```
<label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
```

To

```
<label for="qty"><?php echo $label ?></label>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Saravanavelu!

That works perfect.